# svnX not working on MAC, Its always crash while opening

Tags: macos, svnx

I am using svnx 1.3.4 on MAC , From yesterday it stopped working. I am getting below error. Let me know whats worn there.

```
Process:         svnX [750]
Path:            /Applications/svnX.app/Contents/MacOS/svnX
Identifier:      com.lachoseinteractive.svnX
Version:         1.3.4 (1.3.4)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [182]
Responsible:     svnX [750]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-04-01 12:33:53.826 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  719F8F88-A574-0403-AF99-6E0AC6A1B862


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

VM Regions Near 0x8:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/svnX.app/Contents/MacOS/svnX
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000048000 [  284K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/svnX.app/Contents/MacOS/svnX

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreServicesInternal  0x92499e19 parseAttributeBuffer(__CFAllocator const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char, attrlist const*, void const*, void**, _FileAttributes*, unsigned int*) + 1246
1   com.apple.CoreServicesInternal  0x924a058e corePropertyProviderPrepareValues(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, __CFString const* const*, void const**, long, void const*, __CFError**) + 787
2   com.apple.CoreServicesInternal  0x92495490 prepareValuesForBitmap(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, _FilePropertyBitmap*, __CFError**) + 291
3   com.apple.CoreServicesInternal  0x9249308d _FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKeyInternal(__CFURL const*, __CFString const*, void*, void*, __CFError**, unsigned char) + 190
4   com.apple.CoreServicesInternal  0x92492fc7 _FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey + 45
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x953b4273 CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey + 115
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x953aec07 ____CFRunLoopSetOptionsReason_block_invoke_2 + 1207
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x956503a6 _dispatch_client_callout + 50
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x95650339 dispatch_once_f + 150
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x956511dd dispatch_once + 31
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x953a657a __CFRunLoopSetOptionsReason + 2490
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x953ae740 __CFRunLoopSetOptions + 32
12  com.apple.LaunchServices        0x970f22a5 _LSApplicationCheckIn + 3937
13  com.apple.HIServices            0x9b80ccd0 _RegisterApplication + 7078
14  com.apple.HIServices            0x9b80b123 INIT_Processes + 65
15  com.apple.HIServices            0x9b80b0be GetCurrentProcess + 29
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9be3f328 MenuBarInstance::GetAggregateUIMode(unsigned long*, unsigned long*) + 40
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bc3edef MenuBarInstance::IsVisible() + 49
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9bc3ec08 IsMenuBarVisible + 19
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x97adc6d6 _NSInitializeAppContext + 62
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x97adb87b -[NSApplication init] + 746
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x97adb3aa +[NSApplication sharedApplication] + 153
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x97ad9e84 NSApplicationMain + 281
23  com.lachoseinteractive.svnX     0x00002296 0x1000 + 4758
24  com.lachoseinteractive.svnX     0x000021bd 0x1000 + 4541

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924d0046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc2dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc6cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924d0992 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x956528bd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x95652556 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924d0046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc2dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc6cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x924d0046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc2dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x95fc6cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xbfff9e6c  ebx: 0x0022a628  ecx: 0x8607de2d  edx: 0xbfff9e68
  edi: 0x0000000b  esi: 0xbfff9e64  ebp: 0xbfff9de8  esp: 0xbfff9d30
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010286  eip: 0x92499e19   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xbfff8cfc

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000008
Trap Number:     13
```

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing something similar. To fix it, in the svnX preferences, I changed the path to the svn binaries folder to /usr/bin. My original entry was for an older version of subversion (1.6.xx). After changing to /usr/bin, the version at the top right of the preferences folder now displays 1.7.17.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: A very useful answer. This should be in the svnX website!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with SvnX 2.0. Unfortunately above fix did't help.
What did the job was to purge the cache of all repos.

To do that, go to  **~/Library/Caches/** in Finder and move the folder **app.svnx.two** into the trash (just to have it handy to put it back in case something goes wrong, you can delete it once everything works as expected again).

The whole folder will be regenerated when SvnX starts the next time.
You should now be able to open and use SvnX again and it should work like a charm.
That's what it did for me.